# Apache CXF add namespace in XML response

Tags: xml, apache, rest, cxf

I am trying to return namespace information in the xml response of REST service.
I am using apache cxf 2.7.11.
I have configured

```
</bean>
<!-- Cxf Jaxb Provider -->
<bean id="jaxbXmlProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementProvider">
    <property name="namespacePrefixes" ref="xmlNamespaceMap"></property>  
</bean>
<util:map id="xmlNamespaceMap" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
    <entry value="li" key="http://www.abc.xom/xyz"/>
</util:map>
```

But it does not return any namespace information in the XML response.
I tried to debug the cxf code and found that in org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider class in setNamespaceMapper, the code checks for "namespaceMapperPropertyName", but I am not sure what this property means.

Also if anyone could suggest any other way to return the custom namespace in apache-cxf, that would be really helpful.
thanks

Comment: Please explain with example

Comment: @KarthikPrasad I have a REST service from which I want to return the xml response with namespace and schemalocation attributes. e.g. the xml returned shoule be like this <stationNetwork 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://es.indra.transporte.configuration StationNetwork.xsd" 
    xmlns:ns2="http://es.indra.transporte.configuration" 
    xmlns:com="http://es.indra.transporte.common" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>. I even tried with XMLSchema in the package-info.java but that is also not working.